# Flutter - replacing an item in a list

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this list of `int` which has a length of 3

This is the list:

```
List<Tamount> integer= [
 amount(amount: 2, id: '34'),
 amount(amount: 4, id: '12'),
 TotalAmount(amount: 2, id: '54'),
];
```

And I want to replace index 2 so the one with the amount of 4

I have tried this :

```dart
integer.isNotEmpty
  ? integer.remove(integer[1].id)
  : null;
integers.insert(1, integer(
  id: DateTime.now().toString(),
  amount:34,
));
```

But it is not working ,for some reason it is not removing it from the list, but it is adding to the list.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

If you know the index of the element you want to replace, you don't need to remove existing element from the List. You can assign the new element by index.

```
  integer[1] = amount(amount: 5, id: 'new_id');
```

Comment: after 5 years of programming, i come to forgot some basics XD. thank you .

Comment: @evals we all came to the same conclusion xD

Answer (score 12):

You can do this:

```
integer.isNotEmpty
  ? integer.removeWhere((item)=>item.amount == 4) //removes the item where the amount is 4
  : null;
integers.insert(
  1,
  amount(
    id: DateTime.now().toString(),
    amount:34,
  ));
```

If you want to remove an item by using the index, you can use [removeAt()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/removeAt.html) method:

```
integer.isNotEmpty
  ? integer.removeAt(1) //removes the item at index 1
  : null;
integers.insert(
  1,
  amount(
    id: DateTime.now().toString(),
    amount:34,
  ));
```

Comment: and how would you do this if the list is dynamic and you do not know the amount and you only know the index you want to replace

Comment: You can use removeAt() method on the list and pass the index to it. I updated my answer

Answer (score 5):

In addition, if you want to replace an item at a specific **unknown** index, you can use [indexWhere()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/indexWhere.html) method:

```dart
final index = integers.indexWhere((amount) => amount.id == 4);
integers[index] = Tamount(amount: 3, id: 'ID');
```